# I want to call a mymodule.functions.inc file

Tags: 7, files

Hi all drupalers i am new in drupal coding i wrote a new drupal module that works perfecr but my boss wanted to put all my functions of my .module file in a new folder called 'includes' and in a files that called mymodule.functions.inc now i got an error in my code that says called of undefined function... How I can call this mymodule.functions.inc file in my mymodule.module file?? I need a real help hear guys plz help me out :)

Answer (score 3):

You need to use the [module_load_include](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!module.inc/function/module_load_include/7) function.

EDIT: As @Darvanen mentions this needs to go in your `.module` file preferably inside a suitable hook. Have you seen the [Including code](https://www.drupal.org/coding-standards#includes) section of the Coding standards page?

Comment: yes i read it but where i could call dat module_load_include?

Comment: In your `.module` file which you will still need to have.  The `.module` file is a good place to put your menu hooks, constants and include calls.

Comment: I guess you will add a `module_load_include` at the top of your `.module`, if so: [don't](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!module.inc/function/module_load_include/7). "Do not use this function in a global context since it requires Drupal to be fully bootstrapped, use require_once DRUPAL_ROOT . '/path/file' instead."